# Load the csv data using html view into django database

Tags: django, csv, input

I am trying to load a simple csv file into django model named as class Team

```
class Team(models.Model):
    Team = models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Team
```

Views.py

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'core/model_form_upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

HTML

```
{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>

  <p><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Return to home</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('description', 'document', )
```

I have create a simple html page to load the file into the following location `MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")`

I am able to load my file into that location but I need some help with passing on the data to the actual database and load the values into the table "Team". Any suggestiond on this?

Comment: So you have a view with a form that reads in the csv-file and saves it to `MEDIA_ROOT`, and now you want to add its content to your DB, is that correct? Do you need to keep the file in `MEDIA_ROOT` afterwards?

Comment: Yes. I want to add the contents to the DB and retain the file in the MEDIA_ROOT

Comment: That sounds quite simple: The same form could create the model instances during [form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/). If you make it a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) it will be even easier. If you need more help, please post an excerpt of your CSV and the code of your form validation.

Comment: I have updated the information for the same. I can upload the Team.xls but unable to load it into the model Team.

Comment: I don't see where you copy a csv file to the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory. But that's probably what your `Document` model does. Does this contain a [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield)? Also, your comment suggests that you have an xls file, not a csv. To read this in python, you can use the [`xlrd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) module for example.

Comment: Can you guide me to a sample page that can help me clarify my understanding?

Comment: I'd recommend Google [`xlrd tutorial`](https://www.google.de/search?q=xlrd+tutorial). You should find enough there,